# How can I make my launchpad downloads faster

Tags: caching, proxy, bazaar, launchpad

I am bzr branching some launchpad repositories and it takes very long (hours)

As this is distributed version control, wouldn't it be possible to have a local copy of those repositories (that I could just manually update before I clone them), let's call it a cache machine, and then always clone them? What would be the steps and the commands on the 2 machines (the "local copy" machine and the "target machine"?)

I would prefer not having a bazaar serve as the local copy but just a normal repositoy.

But I expect this would be faster? If not, maybe I could rsync the cache to get the initial branch on the target machine, am I right?

Comment: What version of bzr are you using, and what branch are you cloning? Newer versions are significantly faster, and should no longer take hours.

Comment: @jelmer: I am using the ubuntu 10.04 packages http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/bzr - looks like it is V 2.1. And what you say means I have no luck, those repos are definiteley very old then, they take ages. thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to use a shared repository locally. That way bzr will automatically reuse any revisions present in the shared repository when you clone a branch.

http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/SharedRepositoryTutorial